# UWP list selector to delete part of xml file

Tags: xml, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Creating a UWP windows 10 app which has a list view that is being populated by an xml file in the roaming appdata.

Now I would like to edit that xml file as well in a view when clicking on a list item. I think i get until i delete it but then i don't know how to save it back.

Previously in silverlight application i utilized "stream".

```
 var tmp1 = (Country)PhrasesList.SelectedItem;
            var tmp2 = tmp1.Name;

            string phrasesXMLPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.Path + "/quickphrases.xml");

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(phrasesXMLPath);


            // Retrieve and remove the certain "Mapping" element with its descendants
            var deleted = doc2.Root.Descendants("item").Single(d => d.Element("name").Value == tmp2);
            deleted.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an UWP app, you can use [XmlDocument class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.aspx) to retrieve and create all XML objects.

I assume that your list presents the child nodes(XMLElement) in the XML file, not the texts in one node(XMLText), then for example you can create a list of nodes in the XML and save this file into app's roaming file like this:

```cs
private async void Create_File(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement root = xdoc.CreateElement("List");
    xdoc.AppendChild(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        XmlElement item = xdoc.CreateElement("item" + i);
        root.AppendChild(item);
    }
    XmlElement books = xdoc.CreateElement("Books");
    StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    StorageFile xmlFile = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("XMLList.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await xdoc.SaveToFileAsync(xmlFile);
}
```

This code create a "root" in the XML file, and in this "root" there are 100 items  of nodes, each item is named `"Item" + i`;

Then we need to read these items into a `ListView` like this:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MyList> mylist = new ObservableCollection<MyList>();
private async void Read_Data_Root(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    StorageFile xmlFile = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync("XMLList.xml");
    XmlDocument xdoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);
    txt.Text = xdoc.GetXml(); //show the XML representation of the node and all its descendants in a textblock.
    XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
    mylist.Clear();
    foreach (var item in root.ChildNodes)
    {
        mylist.Add(new MyList { xmlitem = item.GetXml() });
    }  //show all items in a listview
}
```

The class `MyList` is so simple as this:

```cs
public class MyList
{
    public string xmlitem { get; set; }
}
```

I think maybe you have already finish the work all above, then I delete items through `ListView`'s [SelectionChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) and confirm to delete the item in a `Flyout`, here is my `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="Show_Delete_Button" ItemsSource="{x:Bind mylist}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding xmlitem}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Button Content="Delete this item" Click="Delete_Data" />
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</ListView>
```

And the code for deleting data:

```cs
private int selectedindex;

private void Show_Delete_Button(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as ListView);
    selectedindex = listView.SelectedIndex;
}

private async void Delete_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = mylist.ElementAt(selectedindex);
    mylist.RemoveAt(selectedindex); //remove from listview
    StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    StorageFile xmlFile = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync("XMLList.xml");
    XmlDocument xdoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);
    XmlElement root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
    string itemstring = item.xmlitem.TrimStart('<');
    itemstring = itemstring.TrimEnd('>', '/');
    root.RemoveChild(root.GetElementsByTagName(itemstring).FirstOrDefault()); //remove from root element.
    await xdoc.SaveToFileAsync(xmlFile); //save the new list
}
```

This is the code for deleting the node list from XML file. If you created your list in XML file in a different way and construct, please post your code. By the way, here we use the namespace "Windows.Data.Xml.Dom", not the namespace "System.Xml".